# Hide or remove a div class at mobile viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

First and foremost, I am very aware of CSS media queries.  My problem is this: When you have div classes stacked in one div; Example:

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
```

And you want to remove "class2" @media (max-width: 768px)
Creating an output of:

```
<div class="class1"></div>
```

...once the 768px threshold has been reached.

So far I have come up with nothing other than this non-functional code:

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).resize(function () {
  var screen = $(window)    
   if (screen.width < 768) {
    $(".class2").hide();
  }
     else {
       $(".class2").show();
      }
  });
</script>
```

I am really having a hard time finding an answer that works for this.  I do not want to block the entire div's contents!  Just remove one of two classes.

Comment: Wouldn't "responsive design" in this case mean putting the styles for `.class2` into `@media (min-width: 768px) { … }` instead of removing the class via JS? I.e. you don't change the DOM, you sort the styles into breakpoints.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure I get this, but are you just trying to toggle a class?

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    $('.class1').toggleClass('class2', $(window).width() < 768);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pA7Ft/)

jQuery has [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) methods readily available.

Note that `screen` is already defined in javascript.

Comment: No, trying to remove one class while maintaining the other.

Comment: So remove it once the window size is below 768px, and never add it back again, if you're trying to add it back again when the window is resized, you're effectively toggling the class.

Comment: agreed. I am trying to add it back.

Comment: You're the man adeneo! Perhaps I worded my question incorrectly but the only thing I had to do with your code was change the less than to greater than and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Thank You -- I forgot to say.  :)

Comment: I found one problem with this and it was that it would not maintain through page re-load.  I added 'ready' before the 'resize' event and it works! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".class2").removeClass("class2")
```

And you should listen to the `window` not the `document`, so you can modify your code to the following:

```
<script>
 jQuery(window).resize(function () {
  var screen = $(window)    
   if (screen.width < 768) {
    $(".class2").removeClass("class2");
  }
     else {
       $(".class1").addClass("class2");
      }
  });
</script>
```

Of course, this will only toggle `class2` properly if you want all `class1` elements to have `class2` when the screen width is greater than 768. If you don't want that, just add an extra class that has no effect, but acts as a flag indicating which elements should have `class2`.

Comment: no luck with this method but thanks. It's still printing "class2" on the page.

Comment: You probably want to change it from `document` to `window`, if you are checking to see if the window is resized. The document will probably still be the same size even if the window is resized, so the event handler won't even be fired.

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) method:

```
 $(document).resize(function () {
     var screen = $(window);  

     if (screen.width < 768) {
         $('div').removeClass('class2');
     } else {
         $('div').addClass('class2');
     }
```

OR:

```
     screen.width < 768 ? $('div').removeClass('class2') : $('div').addClass('class2');
  });
```

Comment: You can't add the same class more than once using `addClass`. Test it, you will not end up with '<div class="class1 class2 class2">'.  `$('<div class="class2">').addClass("class2")` returns `<div class="class2">`

Comment: You know just deleting the unnecessary block would've been less work than typing out the comment.

Comment: @millimoose, you are right. But I don't have the rep to do that (requires 2000 rep), and the only distinction between this answer and mine was the check to see if the class was already there, so I didn't think it was helpful to try to edit it.

Comment: @RustyToms – I was addressing the author of the question there :)

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions dont work for me. I found this one and it works perfect!

https://codepen.io/richerimage/pen/jEXWWG

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var alterClass = function() {
    var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (ww < 600) {
      $('.test').removeClass('blue');
    } else if (ww >= 601) {
      $('.test').addClass('blue');
    };
  };
  $(window).resize(function(){
    alterClass();
  });
  //Fire it when the page first loads:
  alterClass();
});
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 16px/1.5em sans-serif; 
  color: #111;
}

code {
  background: #ccc;
}

.test {
  background: #fffccc;
  border: solid 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 40px 20px;
}

.test.blue {
  background: dodgerBlue;
}

.test.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h3>Hello World</h3>
  <p>The class of <code>blue</code> is added when I am wider than 600px and is removed when I am 600px or less in width.</p>
</div>
```