# Bootstrap4: div to disappear in mobile view

Tags: bootstrap-4

Is there a way to have the first top div to disappear when resizing or in mobile view.

```
<body>
    <div class="top-area">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Bootstrap responsive display utility classes? http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#how-it-works Please post a complete code to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Check that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819487/hide-or-remove-a-div-class-at-mobile-viewport

You could set a Hidden o 'Visible: false' style to this div when detectes mobile view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide or remove a div class at mobile viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819487/hide-or-remove-a-div-class-at-mobile-viewport)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can combine bootstrap 4 utility classes such as `d-{breakpont}-none` and `d-{breakpoint}-block` to achieve that.

```
<div class="top-area d-none d-md-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            Top Area
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is basically saying `top-area` is displayed none until medium breakpoint `md`. After that, it's displayed as `block`.

**Documentation:** http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/168733/